# Why is my Rspec test failing with duplicate name when name not unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model with these validations:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :repairs
  has_many :services
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :repairs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services

  validates :name, :serial, :model, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :serial
end
```

My factory look like this:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :tool do
    association :location
    association :category
    name {Faker::Name.first_name}
    model {Faker::Company.name}
    serial {Faker::Address.latitude}
  end
end
```

And I have some simple tests like these:

```
it 'is valid with a name, serial, model, location, category' do

  expect(build(:tool, location: Location.new(name: 'Sta 72'),
               category: Category.new(name: 'Chainsaw'))).to be_valid

end

it 'is invalid without a name' do
  expect(build(:tool, name: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:name)
end

it 'is invalid without a serial' do
  expect(build(:tool, serial: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:serial)
end

it 'is invalid without a model' do
  expect(build(:tool, model: nil)).to have(1).errors_on(:model)
end

it 'is invalid with a duplicate serial' do
   tool1 = create(:tool, serial: '12345')
   tool2 = build(:tool, serial: tool1.serial)

  expect(tool2).to have(1).errors_on(:serial)
end
```

Everything works perfect except the last test that checks to make sure `:serial` is unique. It fails with this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
./spec/models/tool_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know why it complains about `Name` when I'm not validating uniqueness of `Name`. Line 27 refers to `tool2 = build(:tool, serial: tool1.serial)`

**edit***
`schema.rb` looks like this:

```
...
  create_table "tools", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "serial"
    t.date     "purchased"
    t.date     "put_in_service"
    t.decimal  "cost"
    t.decimal  "value"
    t.boolean  "in_service"
    t.date     "retired"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "note"
    t.integer  "condition"
    t.text     "old_location"
    t.string   "model"
    t.boolean  "loaner",         default: false
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "tools", ["category_id"], name: "index_tools_on_category_id", using: :btree
  add_index "tools", ["location_id"], name: "index_tools_on_location_id", using: :btree
```

my test log looks like this when I run just the test that's failing:

```
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
 (0.4ms)  BEGIN
 (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
SQL (9.3ms)  INSERT INTO "locations" ("created_at", "name", "type", "updated_at", "vehicle") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00], ["name", "Loaners"], ["type", "Station"], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00], ["vehicle", true]]
 (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 Category Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = 'Chainsaws' LIMIT 1
 SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "categories" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00], ["name", "Chainsaws"], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00]]
 (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 (0.4ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 Tool Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tools" WHERE "tools"."serial" = '12345' LIMIT 1
 SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tools" ("category_id", "created_at", "location_id", "model", "name", "serial", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["category_id", 77], ["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00], ["location_id", 43], ["model", "Stark LLC"], ["name", "Cristina"], ["serial", "12345"], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00]]
 (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "locations" ("created_at", "name", "type", "updated_at", "vehicle") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00], ["name", "Loaners"], ["type", "Station"], ["updated_at", Mon, 27 Jan 2014 22:28:52 PST -08:00], ["vehicle", true]]
 (0.3ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 Category Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = 'Chainsaws' LIMIT 1
 (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
```

**EDIT->**

Thanks to the answers below my problem was solved. The code I used based on their answer is:

```
it 'is invalid with a duplicate serial' do
  chainsaw = create(:category, name: 'Chainsaw')
   tool1 = create(:tool, serial: '12345', category: chainsaw)
   tool2 = build(:tool, serial: '12345', category: chainsaw)

  expect(tool2).to have(1).errors_on(:serial)
end
```

What I don't understand is why FactoryGirl and Faker wouldn't create the two tools and honor the `validates uniqueness` constraint on the `Category` model. Shouldn't it either just reuse the `Category` it just created for the first tool (rather than try to create a new on with the same name) or create a new `Category` for the new tool that is different than the previous one?

aha! this is why:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    name 'Chainsaws'
  end
end
```

I'll set this factory to use Faker and it should work as I was expecting.

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: How about your `location` or `category` models?  They will actually be created by FactoryGirl.build.  Do either of these have `name` as unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a validation error on the implicit creation of the `Category` instance, not of the `Tools` instance.

Since it's occurring on the `build(:tool, ...)` call, we know that the `Category` instance implicitly created to support the `build` conflicts with a previously created `Category` instance. From the log you shared, we can see that both the preceding `create(:tool, ...)` call and the `build(:tool, ...)` are both creating `Category` instances with a name of `Chainsaws`.

(Note: An earlier version of this answer mistakenly hypothesized a conflict with the first example, but that didn't make sense since the name in the first example was `Chainsaw` rather than `Chainsaws`, not to mention the likelihood that transactions are most likely enabled, protecting the last example from the impact of the first.)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had the name of Category as unique. It did not happen on the first `create(:tool...)` because that creates the first instance. When I go to build the second instance it tries to build a new one with the same category name. That is odd to me since shouldn't FactoryGirl and Faker know that it has to build a different category unless told to build it with a specific name? I'll add my working spec to the end of my question.

Comment: It wasn't the previous call that caused the conflict, it was that my factory for `Category` was not using Faker. D'oh!

Comment: Hmmm... not sure about the point at which it rolls back. I assumed that it keeps the records based on `before :all` and `before each`. Still getting my head wrapped around FactoryGirl and Faker. The weird thing is I have another test that saves Factory instances into instance variables, but when I access the variable later in the same `it... do... end` I get different results for any faked attributes. shouldn't it create the fake object, with fake attributes, and have that be the same object with the same attributes throughout? Don't know about how or why to turn transactions on or off...

Comment: Turns out I mistakenly thought the log you posted was for _all_ your examples and not just the last, so I was confused in interpreting the savepoints. I would need to see specifics about your question about instance variables, etc., so please post that as a separate question.  Finally, I updated my answer to better express what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueness constraint being tripped is likely on Category#name. Are you setting that to a static value in your factory?

```
# This causes the associated category to be created
tool1 = create(:tool, serial: '12345')

# The build strategy actually creates associated records.
# This is trying to create a category with a duplicate name.
tool2 = build(:tool, serial: tool1.serial)
```

If you update your Category factory to use a sequence or fake data for name, this should work.

Comment: I accepted the first answer since they were both right, and Peter's came in first. Thanks!